# python+mongoengine error, a int is not a int?

Tags: python

The code is

`mongoengine.connect('admin', host='xxx.dotcloud.com', port=16333 , username='root', password='pass')`

and it shows the error message that:

`09:37:43 [www.0]     raise TypeError("port must be an instance of int")`

I've tried `int(16333)`, still not working.

I'm new to python, could you give me some advise on that? I'm totally confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rest assured that `16333` is indeed an `int`:

```
>>> isinstance(16333, int)
True
```

So, the problem must come from elsewhere. Chances are you have an invalid port number set in your MongoDB [configuration file](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/File+Based+Configuration), and `connect()` tries to parse it even if you provide a `port` argument.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've comment some features which only works on ORM, and then it works!

Comment: I'm not familiar with that configuration, but I'd suggest you examine `settings.py` and double-check if it does not declare a `port` variable which is not a number.

Comment: It is because I've add some ORM-based features, like auth and session. There is no variable `port` I've defined in this file. That's really odd. Anyway, problem solved. Thanks again!